# Border on print using window.print()

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter

i have a issue about the border style on my window.print(). I want is when i print the page the table border is showed. And the privious printing is hidden.

this is my sample code the print is working.

jsfiddle.net/v921/zHt8Y/12/

Answer (score 0):

you are setting border width to 0 first and then again on next line border to 1px. This is what causing an issue.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you need exactly? I am quite confused about your requirements.